# Changing css with jquery on click not restoring object's original css

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, thank you to anyone who takes the time to look at this.
Second, apologies if this is elementary stuff.
Anyway here's the issue:
On the menu page of my portfolio site ([www.henrykember.com](http://www.henrykember.com)), there are buttons that hide and reshuffle item thumbnails based on whether they're day-to-day work ("9-5") or side projects ("5-9"). To show everything again, you click "all".
Clicking these buttons changes the css ("margin-top", margin-left"), so "5-9" items that are normally further down the page come up to the top when all the "9-5" stuff is hidden.
But there's a glitch: when clicking "5-9", then "all" (in that specific order), someo of the "5-9" items don't return to their original css.
These aren't actual buttons, just clickable list items. Is that a problem?
Here's my js:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var fivetonine = $("#fivetonine");
    var ninetofive = $("#ninetofive");
    var all = $("#all");
    var business = $(".business");
    var casual = $(".casual");

            fivetonine.on('click', function ()  {   
        casual.show(200);
        business.hide(200);
        $("a#subsub").css("margin-top", "200px"); 
        $("a#housework").css("margin-top", "160px");
    });

    fivetonine.off('click', function ()  {
        business.show(200);
        casual.show(200);

    });
    
    ninetofive.on('click', function ()  {
        business.show(200);
        casual.hide(200);
        $("a#archive").css("margin-top", "500px");
        $("a#subsub").css("margin-top", "930px");
        $("a#housework").css("margin-top", "1170px");
    });


    ninetofive.off('click', function ()  {
        business.show(200);
        casual.show(200);
    });

    all.on('click', function ()  {
        business.show(200);
        casual.show(200);
        $("a#subsub").css("margin-top", "930px !important");
        $("a#housework").css("margin-top", "1170px");
        $("a#archive").css("margin-top", "1790px");
    });

    all.off('click', function ()  {
        business.show(200);
        casual.show(200);
    });
```

});

Comment: Instead of trying to shuffle stuff around with margins, try something like, `$('#parentContainer').prepend($('.class-of-elements-to-move-to-the-top').detach())`

Comment: @Drew thanks for jumping into this! Alas I have no idea what prepending is. Any chance you could elaborate? No worries if that's too much. Many thanks :)

Comment: I will loop back to this after work today.

Comment: Amazing. My knowledge of js is close to zero, so if there's a way of making my js work that'd be ideal. (If there's a different way, I just need it spelled out a bit!)

Comment: I went a different direction in my answer than my earlier comment of using append.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it has nothing to do with the fact that it's not a button but a list item.

Second, I see that your site uses absolute positioning for the projects showcase. This is a big no-no. I suggest you learn about css-grids and flex-box and integrate one of those for your projects. It will make your life a whole lot easier, as you won't need to mess with margins and so on, as your projects will be positioned dynamically.

I know I wasn't very detailed in this answer, but I hope it helps you anyway. Key take-away: learn about *css-grids* and *flex-box*

Comment: Thanks @George - I do use flex box, but when I redid the layout my media queries got messed up and I went with vw instead of px - which means the flex box is kinda redudant. In each flex item however I do use margins and absolute positioning; I tried to do it without but could never get it to work.
I'm just looking to tweak my 9-5/5-9 selectors so the site works in the short term (I'm jobless and need this to just do its thing when viewed by potential bosses), but mid-term I'll definitely try css grids!

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple bootstrap grid layout solution if your interested.

[working Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s83fxren/)

**Include bootstrap css** in your head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Include bootstrap js** in your head section after loading the jQuery js library

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Basic two column layout:**

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- col 1 -->
  <div class="col-xs-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
  
    <!-- Nine to Five Item -->
    <div class="all ntf">
        9-5
    </div>
    
    <!-- Five to Nine Item -->
    <div class="all ftn">
        5-9
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- col 2 -->
  <div class="col-xs-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
  
    <!-- Nine to Five Item -->
    <div class="all ntf">
        9-5
    </div>
    
    <!-- Five to Nine Item -->
    <div class="all ftn">
        5-9
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- The number of and order of the .ntf and .ftn div elements inside columns 1 and 2 are up to you.
- in the demo, I added colors to these randomly placed div's to make it easier to see the two different content types.
- you can get a more "random" look to your content by adjusting the top/bottom, left/right margin of the content within each of the .ntf/.ftn div's

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btnAll').on('click', function(){
    $('.all').slideDown(500);
  });
  
  $('.btnNineToFive').on('click', function(){
    $('.ftn').slideUp(500);
    $('.ntf').slideDown(500);
  });
  
  $('.btnFiveToNine').on('click', function(){
    $('.ntf').slideUp(500);
    $('.ftn').slideDown(500);
  });

});
```

- I put a half-second (500) delay on all the animations, adjust as you see fit.

If you want random transition times on each element you could replace the `500` with `getRandomInt(100,500)` and include the simple random number function shown below in your script

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Drew - this is super helpful. I'm going to give all these things a go today.